# Preserve comment when post is deleted and I click to reload

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-questions

I was typing a comment under a question, and the owner deleted the question while I was in the middle of typing.  This killed the text I had typed so far, and now I can't get it back.  This seems like suboptimal design to me.  Someone else's action should not delete the text I was typing, with no way for me to recover. (Note that I am a moderator so I can post comments on deleted posts.)

Here's the specific situation where this happened.  I closed a question, and then was in the middle of typing a comment to explain why it was closed and how the poster could improve their question.  The poster deleted their question immediately, before I could finish the comment.  This is the second time it has happened to me.

Now I suppose we could say, if the poster doesn't care about their question, then there's no use in posting a comment anyway.  However, it still feels unfriendly to trash what I've typed so far, without warning, and without possibility of recovering it.

So, that's the problem.  Better behavior would be: if the question is deleted, and I'm in the middle of typing a comment, then preserve the comment text if I 'click to refresh'.  Alternatively, if the question is deleted while I'm typing a comment, don't pop up a notice that prevents me from getting to my text; let me save it by copy-paste before clicking to refresh.

Comment: So write the comment first? You can't submit comments on deleted questions, so saving your half-written comment is pointless.

Comment: It's not a big, you can't submit, a comment to a deleted question

Comment: @Catija, actually, I can, on the site that I moderate: ♦-moderators can post comments on deleted questions, and sometimes users rescue their question and undelete it.  This may be a bit of a special case, admittedly!  As far as "write the comment first", certainly if I knew a user was going to do that on a particular post, I'd do things differently, but it seems unreasonable to adjust my workflow on every post based on this corner case.  OK, I can understand this being declined on the basis that it affects too few users, but I thought I'd document the less-than-optimal UI.

Comment: As a bug, I disagree with this, and it will most likely be marked [tag:status-bydesign]. You have better chance, in my opinion, by marking it as a [tag:feature-request]. (I agree it might not be ideal design by the team, but that's the current behavior, for good or for bad.)

Comment: I updated your question to reflect you are a moderator. That gives some context to your question. I also agree this is a feature request so I tagged it that way. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, OK, it's been edited to be a feature-request.   That works for me too.  (I've never really felt like I fully grokked the difference between the two, so thanks for the suggestion.)